# How to inject \directlua expansions back into TeX files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, latexmk, directlua

Is there a simple way (i.e. a flag to `latexmk`) to preprocess a source TeX file with LuaLaTeX, so that I get back the same source with just the invokations to `\directlua` expanded?

My usecase is that I use a Lua script to generate TikZ code that draws flowers, where I can easily tweak parameters that are passed through a Lua table. Importantly, the `\directlua` invokations are put into prexisting TikZ code (through a high-level `\DrawFlowers` macro), so that I can embed flowers in arbitrary drawings. For instance, the following code draws a five-petals flower, with additional nodes inside the pistil and petals:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
  \DrawFlowers{{
    center = "c",
    pistil = { size = 0.5 },
    petals = { {name="d1"}, {name="d2"}, {name="d3"}, {name="d4"}, {name="d5"} }
  }}
  \node at (d1) {$b$};
  \node at (d2) {$f$};
  \node at (d3) {$e$};
  \node at (d4) {$d$};
  \node at (d5) {$c$};
  \node at (c) {$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have like 40 such drawings each in their own file that are input into my main document, and depend on custom notations and packages loaded in my preamble.

My problem is that I need my document to be able to compile with pdfLaTeX, so that I can upload it on arXiv. Hence the need to remove any dependency to Lua.

Comment: you have not shown any code, but is `\DrawFlowers{` expandable? if it is you can simply `\typeout` each tikzpicture, having made \node` robust.

Comment: One possibility is to write a script that makes a pdf file from a file of tikz code.  Then your main document uses `\includegraphics` on the pdf file instead of `\input` on the tikz file.  You would define a custom dependency for latexmk to invoke the script as needed.  The script could for example create a temporary tex file with a complete document containing the tikz code (or inputting it) and then compile it. After an initial round of making the pdf files, latexmk would only invoke the script for a changed tikz file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried `\typeout` but got weird errors, although `\DrawFlowers` should be expandable since I defined it with `\newcommand` (but I am not very knowledgable in TeX)

@JohnCollins I guess this would be doable, but since in my TikZ code I use macros scattered in various files that depend on various packages, this would be quite complex to setup...

In the end I designed a vim macro that executes the lua code with a normal lua interpreter, and injects back the output into the .tikz file. Then I wrote a little shell script that executes the macro on all files.